# JBOSS EAP 7 - EJB Caller IP

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have migrated my EJB application from 5.0.1 JBOSS to JBOSS EAP 7. 
I want to detect IP address of client in my EJB interceptor (or in bean)

```
String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
result: default task-16
```

Code does not works anymore. How to get IP address of client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try getting remoting Connection and IP address. I'm not sure how reliable it is because `org.jboss.as.security-api` is a deprecated module which may be removed in future versions.

After that try the folowing:

Container interceptor:

```
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.security.Principal;

import org.jboss.remoting3.Connection;
import org.jboss.remoting3.security.InetAddressPrincipal;
import org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingContext;


public class ClientIpInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    private Object iAmAround(final InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        InetAddress remoteAddr = null;
        Connection connection = RemotingContext.getConnection();

        for (Principal p : connection.getPrincipals()) {
            if (p instanceof InetAddressPrincipal) {
                remoteAddr = ((InetAddressPrincipal) p).getInetAddress();
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("IP " + remoteAddr);

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

jboss-ejb3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:ci ="urn:container-interceptors:1.0">

    <jee:assembly-descriptor>
        <ci:container-interceptors>
            <jee:interceptor-binding>
                <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
                <interceptor-class>ClientIpInterceptor</interceptor-class>
            </jee:interceptor-binding>
        </ci:container-interceptors>
    </jee:assembly-descriptor>
</jboss>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.remoting3" />
        <module name="org.jboss.as.security-api" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Connection connection = RemotingContext.getConnection() << is null :(

Comment: @user1028269 I check this solution in EAP7 and works, see https://github.com/fedesierr/eap7-ejb-remote

Comment: I have missed jboss-ejb3.xml interceptor config, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

This article[1] on the JBoss community wiki addresses exactly your issue. Prior to JBoss 5 the IP address apparently has to be parsed from the worker thread name. And that seems to be the only way to do it on earlier versions.

```
private String getCurrentClientIpAddress() {
    String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("Threadname: "+currentThreadName);
    int begin = currentThreadName.indexOf('[') +1;
    int end = currentThreadName.indexOf(']')-1;
    String remoteClient = currentThreadName.substring(begin, end);
    return remoteClient;
}
```

[1]https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowtogettheClientipaddressinanEJB3Interceptor